# how do i make non-numbers into i= form?

Tags: c

Ok, so I have a code that stops only at 0. But wanted to make it so that it will stop when it hit's **any** non-number text. Could anyone help me turning != 0 into non numbers?

The code for this is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    float sum = 1;
    float new_number;
    
    scanf("%f", &new_number);
    
    while (new_number != 0){
        sum += new_number;
        scanf("%f", &new_number); 
    }
    
    printf("Sum: %f\n", sum);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just check the [return value of scanf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html#RETURN_VALUE)

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    float sum = 1;
    float new_number;

    while (scanf("%f", &new_number) > 0) {
        sum += new_number;
    }

    printf("Sum: %f\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```